# Window.resize doesn't work unless page is reloaded

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this responsive layout. What I want to achieve is that at "desktop" size, once a menu link is clicked it will navigate to that part of the page. I want the same thing for "mobile" size. Also, once the menu links are clicked, the menu will slideUp.

I have both of these things working, however it only works when the page is reloaded. To summarize, here are the problems:

1. At desktop size: navigation is fine, but when resized to mobile the menu doesn't show.
2. At mobile size: navigation works fine, when resized to desktop it also works fine, but the menu keeps on toggling.

I created a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1341papd/8/) for it. Here is my code:

### HTML

```
<div id="head" class="clearfix">
    <a href="#" title="Pull Menu" id="pull">Pull Menu</a>
    <div class="menu-wrap clearfix">
        <div class="nav">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#test1" title="test1">test1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#test2" title="test2">test2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#test3" title="test3">test3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="test1" class="section">Test1</div>
<div id="test2" class="section">Test2</div>
<div id="test3" class="section">Test3</div>
```

### JavaScript

```
var respMenu = function(event) {
    var menu        = $('.menu-wrap');
    if ($(window).width() < 501) {  
        $("#pull").on('click', function() {
            menu.slideToggle('slow');
        });
        $(".nav ul li a").click(function() {
            menu.slideUp('slow');
        });
    }
    else{

    }
    return false;
    event.preventDefault();
};

var onClick = function() {
   $('a').bind('click',function(event){
       var $anchor = $(this);

       if ($(window).width() > 500) {
            $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top - 90 }, 1000,'easeInOutExpo');
        }
        else{

            $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top - 50 }, 1000,'easeInOutExpo');
        }

       event.preventDefault();
    });
};

$(window).load(function(){
    respMenu();
    onClick();
});
$(window).resize(function(){
    respMenu();
    onClick();
});
```

Comment: your demo has no link. please update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you bind a new handler to the click event each time your `window` is re-sized and you never unbind them. So the handlers number keep increasing, which means that multiple events will be fired after a click once you've re-sized the window.

So what you can do is to unbind the handlers using the `unbind` or `off` methods.

Take a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/yohanrobert/p987prdd/